# Can you move around Heart Containers in The Legend of Zelda: Tears of the Kingdom?

Tags: zelda-tears-of-the-kingdom

In The Legend of Zelda: Tears of the Kingdom, defeating the boss of one of the four regional Temples causes a Heart Container to drop. Is it possible to force one of these heart containers to move, through:

- Ultrahand
- Recall
- Zonai vehicles
- Any other method you can think of

Comment: Of course, I don't even think to try to use ultrahand on the heart container before picking it up...

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I'm just curious.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, the heart container is not able to be interacted with besides picking up by touching it. I just defeated one of the temples, and confirmed before picking it up that none of Link's powers (ultrahand, recall, fuse) can be used on it. I  also tried a few Zonai devices (e.g. launching a rocket into it) and none of them had any effect.

Comment: I suppose it makes sense for them to make it so you can't use the heart container to fuse a 1 trillion damage weapon...

Comment: I tried this as well.  The only "interaction" I was able to cause was a metallic sound effect if you bump something else into the heart container with ultrahand.  The heart container doesn't budge, though.